# Multiple values validation using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multiple-select

I need to add validation from multiple selection, if i select one value, then  i need to fill text field whereas if i select two or more, then i need empty text field.

Multiple values store in the **test** array we can get values `test[0]` , `test[1]` etc.

[image of interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhiJp.png)

Below code is working but if i select two or more values it also fill the `test[0]` values in the text field.

Please help me. Thank you.

**here i work in platform (progress roll base) so interface not hard code**

```js
$('#R3413775').change(function() {

  var test = "";

  test = rbf_getFieldValue("R3413775");

  if (test != "") {

    getbankdetails();

  } else if (test == "") {
    $("#Account_Number").val("");
    $("#Branch_Code").val("");
    $("#Account_Name").val("");
  }


});
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear how you want to achieve this, so perhaps it would be a good idea to include your html

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Actually here i working in the platform so i do not write the html code.under the platform we identify the specific field using integration name ,according  to above  integration name is R3413775 ,it is like id

Comment: @Eddie it is mistake i change it but not work properly

Comment: What does `rbf_getFieldValue` do and what kind of element has id `R3413775`? Since `test` is always assigned with `rbf_getFieldValue` call's result, it's propably different than `""` (you mentioned that `test` is an array)

Comment: @barbsan rbf_getFieldValue it is an API it is work as $( "" ).val()  in jquery it store the values from input field.id R3413775 has a multiple selection field

Comment: @barbsan here i put the image of interface https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhiJp.png        company filed is `R3413775`

Comment: Based on what you've got, it sounds like `rbf_getFieldValue` isn't behaving as it should. That is the code you need to troubleshoot. Can you please reformat your question to include the function that is causing the issue?

Comment: I still have no idea what has id `R3413775` - bank select, that field with popup or whole form? And your code seems to compare array with empty string, so that `getbankdetails` is always called, unless `test` is `[]`. And no idea what happens in `getbankdetails`